# Error on 'Newsletter Subscribers'

Tags: error, newsletter, magento1.9.3.1

When accessing the following in Magento backend:

`Magento Admin Panel > Newsletter > Newsletter Subscribers`

I get the following error:

```
"You cannot define a correlation name 'customer_lastname_table' more than once"
#0 /var/www/magento_dir/lib/Varien/Db/Select.php(281): Zend_Db_Select->_join('left join', Array, 'customer_lastna...', Array, NULL)
#1 /var/www/magento_dir/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Select.php(373): Varien_Db_Select->_join('left join', Array, 'customer_lastna...', Array, NULL)
#2 /var/www/magento_dir/app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/Model/Resource/Subscriber/Collection.php(145): Zend_Db_Select->joinLeft(Array, 'customer_lastna...', Array)
#3 /var/www/magento_dir/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Newsletter/Subscriber/Grid.php(59): Mage_Newsletter_Model_Resource_Subscriber_Collection->showCustomerInfo(true)
#4 /var/www/magento_dir/app/code/community/BL/CustomGrid/Model/Grid/Rewriter/Eval.php(32) : eval()'d code(96): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Newsletter_Subscriber_Grid->_prepareCollection()
#5 /var/www/magento_dir/app/code/community/BL/CustomGrid/Model/Grid/Rewriter/Eval.php(32) : eval()'d code(382): BL_CustomGrid_Block_Rewrite_Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Newsletter_Subscriber_Grid->_prepareCollection()
#6 /var/www/magento_dir/app/code/community/BL/CustomGrid/Model/Observer.php(562): BL_CustomGrid_Block_Rewrite_Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Newsletter_Subscriber_Grid->blcg_finishPrepareCollection()
#7 /var/www/magento_dir/app/code/community/BL/CustomGrid/Model/Grid/Rewriter/Eval.php(32) : eval()'d code(93): BL_CustomGrid_Model_Observer->afterGridPrepareCollection(Object(BL_CustomGrid_Block_Rewrite_Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Newsletter_Subscriber_Grid))
#8 /var/www/magento_dir/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(643): BL_CustomGrid_Block_Rewrite_Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Newsletter_Subscriber_Grid->_prepareCollection()
#9 /var/www/magento_dir/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(649): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_prepareGrid()
#10 /var/www/magento_dir/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(922): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_beforeToHtml()
#11 /var/www/magento_dir/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(641): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#12 /var/www/magento_dir/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(585): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('grid', true)
#13 /var/www/magento_dir/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/newsletter/subscriber/list.phtml(35): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('grid')
#14 /var/www/magento_dir/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/magento...')
#15 /var/www/magento_dir/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#16 /var/www/magento_dir/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#17 /var/www/magento_dir/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#18 /var/www/magento_dir/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(923): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#19 /var/www/magento_dir/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#20 /var/www/magento_dir/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(923): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#21 /var/www/magento_dir/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(641): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#22 /var/www/magento_dir/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(585): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#23 /var/www/magento_dir/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page.phtml(74): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#24 /var/www/magento_dir/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/magent...')
#25 /var/www/magento_dir/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#26 /var/www/magento_dir/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#27 /var/www/magento_dir/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#28 /var/www/magento_dir/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(923): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#29 /var/www/magento_dir/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#30 /var/www/magento_dir/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#31 /var/www/magento_dir/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Newsletter/SubscriberController.php(57): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#32 /var/www/magento_dir/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Newsletter_SubscriberController->indexAction()
#33 /var/www/magento_dir/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#34 /var/www/magento_dir/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#35 /var/www/magento_dir/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#36 /var/www/magento_dir/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#37 /var/www/magento_dir/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#38 {main}";s:3:"url";s:90:"/index.php/admin/newsletter_subscriber/index/key/112d139b39001ee18f7035eb72768c23/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

I did not change any code. I moved Magento lately and I think it happened after that.

Comment: Can you append your  Grip.php code here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen this issue before where the BL_CustomGrid module loads 2 of the same tables and give you this issue. so your custom grid configuration is off. Try to remove it. or try to disable that module to see if indeed its the issue.

Comment: I've tried to disable this module. But that didn't work. Same error.

Comment: When you disabled it. you saw in deed the original grid? (also on other pages) just to be sure its not cached or anythign

Comment: I have made an exception for the block `adminhtml/newsletter_subscriber_grid`, so the module ignores this grid. Now it works again. Thanks.

Comment: Perfect. Thank for choosing my answer ;-)

Comment: you can exclude the subscriber grid, by going to **admin -> configuration -> ENHANCED ADMIN GRIDS >  Base Configuration > Global Exclusions** and add this **adminhtml/newsletter_subscriber_grid** in the *block type* and * in *Rewriting Class*